# Creating built-in types with the new expression

Tags: c++, initialization

Let's consider the following simple program:

```
int main()
{
    int *a = new int;
}
```

Is it reliable that the value of `*a` is `0`. I'm **not** sure about that because primitives don't have default-initialization:

> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> (7.1) — If T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9),
>   constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are
>   enumerated (13.3.1.3), and the best one for the initializer () is
>   chosen through overload resolution (13.3). The constructor thus
>   selected is called, with an empty argument list, to initialize the
>   object.
>
> (7.2) — If T is an array type, each element is default-initialized.
>
> (7.3) — **Otherwise, no initialization is performed**.

I'd say that `*a` is not initializaed so accessing it would lead to UB. Is that correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be absolutely clear, consider

```
int *a = new int;

int *b = new int();
```

`*a` is **not initialised**, `*b` is initialised to 0.

Use of `*a` prior to initialisation is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ah, haven't noticed your answer. Couldn't you add a little clarafication. I just don't understand why new int and new int() is different?

Comment: Simply put, it's the language rules. Think of `int()` as calling a constructor with a default argument set to 0. Similarly, `new int(5)` creates an integer with value 5 and returns a pointer to it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

You can value-initialize it (i.e set it to zero for an `int`) by using `new int()`.

Comment: So, it's reasonble to ask why? Why is it reliable? `new int` cause default initialization to be performed....

Comment: @St.Antario as you quoted from the Standard, default-initialization for a built-in type is a no-op, which means that you retrieve any old garbage value that was laying around there (UB in standardese)

Comment: @Quentin Got it, but why does `new int()` have different behavior? I don't understand...

Comment: @St.Antario I can't give you a better answer than "because the Standard says so". [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) is a comprehensive list of possible initialization types. Caution : there are quite a lot :)

Comment: @Quentin Indeed, found it. __An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized.__ Value initialization means zero-initialization for built-in types.